# Unable to scrape data inside div tag from a website that requires search inputs

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to web scraping and I want to get names of relevant projects from this [website](https://www.devex.com/funding/r?report=grant-21654&query%5B%5D=big+data&filter%5Bstatuses%5D%5B%5D=forecast&filter%5Bstatuses%5D%5B%5D=open&filter%5Bupdated_since%5D=2019-09-03T14%3A27%3A15.234Z&sorting%5Border%5D=desc&sorting%5Bfield%5D=_score) search results. The project names are inside h4 tags

The website requires login and passowrd to see the details of project but I just want to get a list of all the projects.

After looking around, I realized to scrape results, I have to give input from the code. The code I am using is as below

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Referer': 'https://www.devex.com/login?return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.devex.com%2Ffunding%2Fr%3Freport%3Dgrant-21475%26query%255B%255D%3Dbig%2Bdata%26filter%255Bstatuses%255D%255B%255D%3Dforecast%26filter%255Bstatuses%255D%255B%255D%3Dopen%26filter%255Bupdated_since%255D%3D2019-09-02T04%253A57%253A27.714Z%26sorting%255Border%255D%3Ddesc%26sorting%255Bfield%255D%3D_score',
}

params = (
    ('report', 'grant-21475'),
    ('query[]', 'big data'),
    ('filter[statuses][]', ['forecast', 'open']),
    ('filter[updated_since]', '2019-09-02T04:57:27.714Z'),
    ('sorting[order]', 'desc'),
    ('sorting[field]', '_score'),
)

response = requests.get('https://www.devex.com/funding/r', headers=headers, params=params)

result = bs(response.text, 'html.parser')
```

The result I am getting does not contain required tags or information.
Please let me know.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content is returned dynamically from an API call you can find in network tab of browser

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.devex.com/api/funding_projects?query[]=big+data&filter[statuses][]=forecast&filter[statuses][]=open&filter[updated_since]=2019-09-03T14:27:15.234Z&page[number]=1&page[size]=1000&sorting[order]=desc&sorting[field]=_score').json()
titles = [project['title'] for project in r['data']]
print(len(titles))
```

You could alter page param in a loop and page size. First request would tell you how many total results there are. I simply put a number larger than the expected results count in this instance.

Example loop:

```
import requests
import math

titles = []
page_size = 500

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(f'https://www.devex.com/api/funding_projects?query[]=big+data&filter[statuses][]=forecast&filter[statuses][]=open&filter[updated_since]=2019-09-03T14:27:15.234Z&page[number]=1&page[size]={page_size}&sorting[order]=desc&sorting[field]=_score').json()
    total = int(r['total'])
    titles += [project['title'] for project in r['data']]
    if total > page_size:
        num_pages = math.ceil(total/page_size)
        for page in range(2, num_pages+1):
            r = s.get(f'https://www.devex.com/api/funding_projects?query[]=big+data&filter[statuses][]=forecast&filter[statuses][]=open&filter[updated_since]=2019-09-03T14:27:15.234Z&page[number]={page}&page[size]={page_size}&sorting[order]=desc&sorting[field]=_score').json()
            titles += [project['title'] for project in r['data']]
print(len(set(titles)))
```

Comment: Thank you. This is working. However, it only gives my the names of projects that are currently shown on the page. Not the full list. For example, the search result shows 661 projects and the page is showing only 20. I have to move to next page to see next 20 and so on. Is there a way, I can get the names of all the projects?

Comment: Edited. Note that there are actually only 645 unique titles.